# Qt Android. Get device screen resolution

Tags: android, qt, screen, resolution, pixel

I'm developing in qt 5.3 on android device. I can't get the screen resolution.
With the old qt 5 version this code worked:

```
QScreen *screen = QApplication::screens().at(0);
largh=screen->availableGeometry().width();
alt  =screen->availableGeometry().height();
```

However now it doesn't work (returns a screen size 00x00). Is there another way to do it? thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Size](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qscreen.html#size-prop) holds the pixel resolution

```
screen->size().width()
screen->size().height();
```

Whereas, [availableSize](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qscreen.html#availableSize-prop) holds the size excluding window manager reserved areas...

```
screen->availableSize().width()
screen->availableSize().height();
```

More info on the [QScreen](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qscreen.html) class.

Answer (score 2):

for more information, screen availableSize is not ready at the very beginning, so you have to wait for it, here is the code:

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent){
...   
QScreen *screen = QApplication::screens().at(0);
connect(screen, SIGNAL(virtualGeometryChanged(QRect)), this,SLOT(getScreen(QRect)));
}

void Widget::getScreen(QRect rect)
{
    int screenY = screen->availableSize().height();
    int screenX = screen->availableSize().width();
    this->setGeometry(0,0,screenX,screenY);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that there are several ways to obtain the device resolution, each outputs the same results and thankfully works across all Os-es supported by Qt...

**1)** My favorite is to write a static function using [QDesktopWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdesktopwidget.html) in a reference class and use it all across the code:

```
QRect const CGenericWidget::getScreenSize()
{
    //Note: one might implement caching of the value to optimize processing speed. This however will result in erros if screen resolution is resized during execution
    QDesktopWidget scr;

    return scr.availableGeometry(scr.primaryScreen());
}
```

Then you can just call across your code the function like this:

```
qDebug() << CGenericWidget::getScreenSize();
```

It will return you a [QRect](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qrect.html) const object that you can use to obtain the screen size without the top and bottom bars.

**2)** Another way to obtain the screen resolution that works just fine if your app is full screen is:

```
QWidget *activeWindow = QApplication::activeWindow();
m_sw = activeWindow->width();
m_sh = activeWindow->height();
```

**3)** And of course you have the option that Zeus recommended:

```
QScreen *screen = QApplication::screens().at(0);
largh=screen->availableSize().width();
alt  =screen->availableSize().height();
```